# Get IP address of KVM Guest vm

Tags: bash, ip, centos7, kvm

Is there a way I can get the IP address of a KVM guest client using bash?  I need to add this to a bash script to automate a process and part of it is needing to get the IP address of the VM and pass it into a variable.

I've seen multiple things online but none of them seem to work.

Any help or advice will be appreciated

Comment: KVM is just the kernel part of the virtualization stack. I'm assuming you're using libvirt and it is libvirt managing the networks?

Comment: That is correct, I am using libvirt and it is managing the networks

Comment: ok so I tried the virsh domifaddr <domain> command but that didn't return any results.  I'm missing something here, but not sure what.

Comment: virsh domifaddr only returns DHCP leases for the named VM. It returns nothing if the VM is not running or has only static IPs.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a `get-vm-ip` script (which you can download from https://github.com/earlruby/create-vm/blob/master/get-vm-ip) which uses this to get the IP:

```
HOSTNAME=[your vm name]
MAC=$(virsh domiflist $HOSTNAME | awk '{ print $5 }' | tail -2 | head -1)
arp -a | grep $MAC | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

The virsh command gets the MAC address, the last line finds the IP address using `arp`.

Comment: `virsh -q` gets rid of the header stuff, so you can skip the `tail` and `head` stuff.

Comment: And on Linux `arp -e` or just simply `arp` will simplify extracting ip from the last output

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$(for mac in `sudo virsh domiflist $buildname |grep -o -E "([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}([0-9a-f]{2})"` ; do sudo arp -e |grep $mac  |grep -o -P "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" ; done)
#iphost="$ip   appliance"

echo $ip
```